# Expression to pull text from a "Comments" field

Tags: text, replace, reporting-services, format, field

I need to pull the text in a comments field into an SSRS report. The text is separate multiple lines and I need it to read as separate lines.

The current code pulling from Crystal Reports is

```
"=Replace(Replace(Fields!PartNum_MfgComment.Value, chr(13), vbCrLf ) , chr(10), vbCrLf )"
```

and it doesn't give errors when uploading to SSRS, but the text in that field does not show on my report.
It should look like this...

```
 "WIS: Qty (6) Width (9.53mm) C-Dim (134mm) Angle (10°)
```

Per Cust Sample"

Comment: Please take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: And use proper tag. SSRS was important to mention

Comment: The "How to.." that you suggested only showed how to add a <br/> if that's even a thing... I'm looking for the function that will cause it to pull in whatever text is in that comments section.

Comment: Right!  SSRS should've been my first "tag"... I'll do better...

Comment: Thanks, my link sucks. This one is better: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: If I understood... you have a field in your dataset that contains text separated by `CHR(13) CHR(10)` and you want that to appear as multiple lines of text in your SSRS report? If that's the case then you should not need to do anything, it should show correctly without any expressions. You crystal function seems to be replacing `CHR(13)+CHR(10)` with `vbcrlf` which is just shorthand for `CHR(13)+CHR(10)`. The only thing it will be doing is adding an extra blank line.

Comment: ... and Gilles was just showing you how to format code in your question so your question is easier to read, it was not intended to help solve you problem.

Comment: Gilles and Alan, Thank you for your input and advice. Like my name says, I am a newbie to this coding thing, I am not trying to be difficult and I don't always understand the lingo, so please be patient as I take your advice and learn how to do this. If this is not the place for newbie advice, then let me know and I'll stop asking questions.  And Gilles was totally correct... The SSRS tag was very important to mention.  Since the majority of my questions are SSRS... I should make that my first mention... every time.

Comment: Alan - The CR syntax that I posted yields the data/text strings contained in a comments area... what I attempted to do is use that exact syntax in my SSRS to yield the same result... only things is is that it did not work. So, I think what I am asking for is... Is the "REPLACE" function the correct way to extract the data/text strings contained in my comments area?

Comment: Also, I did some research right after the initial post about the CHR (13) & (10) and saw the SSRS equivalent is vbcrlf or vbcr or vblf depending on which is relevant... thank you for that though. I am assuming that these are in the syntax so the data is separated by the line break when it is pulled into the report?

Comment: My report should pull the following information and put the data/text string on the report in separate lines...  KW should be a new line... WOS should be a new line... WIS should be a new line...
KW1: Qty (12) Width (9.8mm) Depth (0mm) Type (SQ)
   
WOS: Qty (2) Width (12.7mm) A-Dim (215.9mm) Angle (-10°)
   
WIS: Qty (2) Width (12.7mm) C-Dim (139.7mm) Angle (-10°)